# how to disable future dates in (date range 01/04/2015 to 31/03/2016) but don't need 24/06/2015,25/06/2015 etc(From Today)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I don't need future date including the date range with from date

```
$(function() {
        var financial_year=2015-2016;
        //financial_year=document.getElementById("financial_year").value;   
        var first = financial_year.substring(0, 4);
        var second = financial_year.substring(5, 9);
        var minYear=first;
        var maxYear=second;
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
            changeYear: true,
             dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
             minDate: new Date(minYear,3,01),
             maxDate: new Date(maxYear,3,01),
             dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
         });
    });
```

Please advise me

Comment: financial_year would equal -1?

Comment: no financial year like 2015-2016

Comment: Ah, ok, a typo in the code then. Should be: var financial_year="2015-2016" (in quotes).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own [`beforeShowDay` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)

Similarly to this http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days

```
var disabledDates = [...];

function noDays(date) {
    return [disabledDates.indexOf(date) != -1, "", ""];
}

jQuery('#date').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: noDays
});
```

You can also write this to disable date range:

```
function noDays(date) {
    return [date > startDate && date < endDate, "", ""];
}
```

Comment: i need disable all future date from today including the date range.not a specific  date

Comment: In `noDays` function you can write any conditions, including range checking

Comment: I don't understand you. What is the problem? Try to explain more detailed. I fixed my example, but first look at mentioned reference link